# Error: Corrupted Git Object Files - Unable to Commit Changes

Tags: linux, git, github, continuous-integration, git-commit

I encountered an error while trying to commit changes to my Git repository. The error message indicates that several object files within the .git/objects directory are corrupted or missing. Here's the specific error message I received:

```
error: object file .git/objects/e5/478f3374c7ac2dadd215ac2600ccfaa8ebd3c2 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/7a/7127dac0823acb8b09acfd8f44b54a17c9854a is empty
fatal: could not parse HEAD
```

These were the following steps I attemped:

1. I tried locating the hash of the corrupted file and deleting them.
2. Additionally, running git fsck revealed several corrupted or missing object files with hash values like e5478f3374c7ac2dadd215ac2600ccfaa8ebd3c2, 7a7127dac0823acb8b09acfd8f44b54a17c9854a, etc.

I'm seeking assistance on how to resolve this issue. I understand that it may involve locating and potentially deleting the corrupted object files, but I'm unsure about the exact steps to take. Any guidance or advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no easy help. Ask your favorite search engine for "salvage corrupted git repository".

Comment: Do you keep your Git repository in a directory that is synched to the cloud (OneDrive or similar)?

Comment: @j6t No I don't store any files in the cloud. Though I intend to in the future.

Comment: Be warned that cloud sync tools like OneDrive tend to destroy a repository at the blink of an eye with no advance warning.